# angular 6 to 8, angular universal, Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I try to upgrade the angular version and re-establish the new version of angular universal.

**Angular universal insatall**:

`ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [project name]`

**Bulid project**

`npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

**package.json**

```
"serve:ssr": "node dist/server/main.js",
"build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run [project name]:server:production",
```

**Error message**:

```
ERROR in ./server.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):...
...server.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property....
```

`server.ts` was created by command `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [project name]`

**server.ts**:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

I originally built the old version of universal, I do n’t know if there is a conflict, I have encountered many problems during this update ..

Comment: I got it to work by adding , "files": ["../server.ts"] to tsconfig.server.json and tsconfig.app.json